# Grouping by Fiscal Year (Oracle)

Tags: oracle

Is there a way in Oracle that can pull the FY? I used the script below to pull just two FY. Mytable date range is from FY1998 to FY2009.

```
 SELECT 'FY2008' as FY, 
         Site, 
         COUNT(*) 
    FROM mytable 
   WHERE date >='10-OCT-2007' 
     AND date <'10-OCT-2008' 
GROUP BY site
```

---

```
 SELECT 'FY2008' as FY, 
         Site, 
         COUNT(*) 
    FROM mytable 
   WHERE date >='10-OCT-2008' 
     AND date <'10-OCT-2009' 
GROUP BY site
```

---

Pulling two FY is OK but it's too much repeatative when pulling more than 10 FY.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add 83 days to your date and truncate it to whole year:

```
select 'FY'||TRUNC(date + 83, 'YYYY') as FY, Site, count(*)
from mytable
group by 'FY'||TRUNC(date + 83, 'YYYY'), site
```

Comment: +1 although I'd use a single 'Y' instead of 4 and "interval '83' day" instead of just 83. But TRUNC is much better than TO_CHAR here.

Comment: @SunWKim - because 10-OCT is always (even on leap years) 83 days before the end of the year, so if you add 83 days and trunc it to whole year, you get the year 2013 for all days between 10-OCT-2012 and 09-OCT-2013.

Comment: @eumiro - I see, that's very smart. I am used to working in calendar quarters, but your way is faster.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Oracle 9i+, use a CASE expression:

```
  SELECT CASE 
           WHEN TO_CHAR(t.date, ) = 10 AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM t.date) >= 10 THEN 
            'FY' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.date) + 1
           WHEN TO_CHAR(t.date, ) > 10 THEN 
            'FY' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.date) + 1
           ELSE
            'FY' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.date) 
         END AS FY,
         t.site, 
         COUNT(*) 
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.site, FY
```

Comment: When t.date is on 01-November? EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t.date) >= 10 but not EXTRACT(DAY FROM t.date) >= 10

Answer (score 2):

And for completeness, in addition to @eumiro answer. In countries (such as Australia) which have a financial year running from 1 July to 30 June, you can replace the 83 with **184**.

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

You can use the to_char function here.  Check this link for an explanation:
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php

You may also try using a case statement

```
select case when date >='10-OCT-2007' and date <'10-OCT-2008' then 'FY08'
            when date >='10-OCT-2008' and date <'10-OCT-2009' then 'FY09'
            else 'Other' end as fiscal_year, count(*)
  from mytable
 group by  case when date >='10-OCT-2007' and date <'10-OCT-2008' then 'FY08'
            when date >='10-OCT-2008' and date <'10-OCT-2009' then 'FY09'
            else 'Other' end
```

Ultimately, if you have create table privileges you may want to consider making a date lookup table.  Search for "date dimension" in data warehousing guides.

For example:
Your table would have
date, date_desc, fiscal_year, etc....

then you could just join and group by fiscal year, or whatever else you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to easily determine the Fiscal Year of a date for those who's Fiscal Year runs from July to June:

```
SELECT 'FY'||TO_CHAR(ROUND(your_date_here,'YEAR'),'YY') AS FY
```